# scroll-to-top button on a mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the Scroll To Top button appear once the user started scrolling down, instead of it always being present, even when being at the top. Quick note, I barely have experience with JS, so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Anyway here is the page I'm having an error on: http://www.m.evans-carpentry.com/gallery/projects/

```js
<script>
   $(function() {
    var $elem = $('#content');
    
    $('#nav_up').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#nav_down').fadeIn('slow');  
    
    $(window).bind('scrollstart', function(){
     $('#nav_up,#nav_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.2'});
    });
    $(window).bind('scrollstop', function(){
     $('#nav_up,#nav_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
    });
    
    $('#nav_down').click(
     function (e) {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
     }
    );
    $('#nav_up').click(
     function (e) {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
     }
    );
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Share your full code, its can be hopeful.

Comment: Your jquery file isn't being loaded properly. You might want to get that checked first.

Comment: devtools is a great instrument for debugging. You have some errors in your JS, for first correct it. Eg `$ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

you call jquery earlier announcements of jquery on line 30

```
<script>$('#nav Li: has (ul)').doubleTapToGo ();</script>
```

insert this line after the call jquery

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complex, try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        //Click event to scroll to top
        $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

".scrollToTop" is the thing to be clicked that scrolls back to the top of the page.